# Neighborhoods in MetPy

Tags: nearest-neighbor, metpy

Does MetPy have a built in tool to deal with neighborhood functions applied to a meteorological parameter grids, such as fractional coverage within some radius of influence?  I had constructed something with GEMPAK several years ago but didn't know if that sort of feature existed elsewhere.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only things that sound remotely like that are the implementations of Barnes and Cressman interpolation, as well as some smoothing functions. That doesn't sound like what you really want. Feel free to open a [feature request](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/new), though.